# Dialogflow CX avatar image URI

Tags: javascript, json

I need to change dummy avatar image of bot in dialog flow CX?

Looking for avatar change option in CX but cannot find any solution for it. Can anyone help me on it where I can change this please share json or javascript code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.